# Cant close dismissible alerts bootstrap in type script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-5

The close button of a very simple piece of code is not working, the alert is rendered ok, but the close button doesn't do anything. I have `bootstrap 5.2.3`. I have a simple main and app file.  `App.tsx` file:

```
  return (
      <div
        className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show"
        role="alert"
      >
        <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those
        fields below.
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="alert"
          aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
      </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

And the main.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Because that's not how React works? If you don't want to use React, why are you using it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? This attitude is not very helpful. It seems that incorporating bootstrap styling is a rather common practice, and this is the simplest code I could provide for the alert.

Comment: I'm sorry if my attitude comes across as unhelpful. React can and will totally overwrite anything in the part of the DOM it renders to, which is usually all of it. So anything that you add to the page that has it's own view of the world like bootstrap isn't going to work. "Incorporating bootstrap styling is a rather common practice" yeah, for *styling*, not **behavior**.  If you want a tighter integration [this is a thing](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

Comment: Or to put it a slightly different way, given that is all React 101, your question comes across as "I copy-pasted a bunch of code from different doc sites together but it doesn't work and I don't know why", which is why I was fairly brusque in the initial comment. If you want to use React you're going to have to actually learn it, it's not something you can just drop on the page and expect it to work.

Comment: It was more of, in a piece of a tutorial, bootstrap has been used so far for some of the components, and It is not an insane idea that some behaviours described might work together. So yes, it is React 101, I just learned that behaviour stuff might just not work. This was not mentioned, and I've been trying to find out the cause of the problem for a while. Thank you for your answer, that was really helpful!

Comment: I use [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts). It has a bit of a learning curve, but it (or another similar library) is the right way to incorporate Bootstrap. Just loading the raw library is anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but I've done this before like below. IMHO dealing with [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/home-installation--page) (installation instructions in link) produces more legible code than using bootstrap directly and repetitively calling class names. Plus, it works and their docs are great. You can still use bootstrap class names when you want to, as seen in the `<p>` tag in the example below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'reactstrap';

const Alert: React.FC = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const onDismiss = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  }

  return (
    <Alert color="danger" isOpen={visible} toggle={onDismiss}>
      <p className="mb-3">I'm an alert!</p>
    </Alert>
  );
}
```